# PHP, Mysql getting archive by MONTH from strtotime

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm building a blog page. But I'm starting to struggle on the archive section.

I have comments in mysql that are time stamped using:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($month . " " . $date . " " . $year . " " . $time);
```

Now if I have a link that goes to: `blog.php?Month=Febuary&Year=2012`

How would I use those two parameters in a sql query to retrieve all records for that month and year?

Thanks,
ben

Comment: How do you store the data in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Changed them to use UNIX timestamps...

There is no need for `strtotime()` to query by month & year. Instead you can just do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blogtbl
WHERE 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(postdate)) = 2012
  AND UPPER(MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(postdate))) = 'FEBRUARY'
```

It can also be done with `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM blogtbl
WHERE 
  UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(postdate), '%M %Y')) = 'FEBRUARY 2012'
```

**Note** I use `UPPER()` to convert the query to uppercase, just to make it easier to pass in PHP variables with unpredictable casing.

We assume you already know how to retrieve the month and year from the query string in PHP via `$_GET['Month'], $_GET['Year']` and properly escape them for insertion into your query.

Comment: tryed this but not having much luck,

my mysql has a timestamp in unix format '1326905520'

Comment: @BenStringer See changes above using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert unix timestamps to MySQL DATETIME.